# What am I doing wrong when I add my fragment to my activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So basically, whenever I launch my app, it pops up and then cancels. The purpose of the app is to click one of 3 buttons and it will set an ImageView to that picture, but i wanted to experiment with fragments. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements awkwardfragment.hello {

ImageView Ryan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });




}

@Override
public void changer(int a) {
    Ryan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(a == 1){
        Ryan.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_frog);
    }
    else if(a == 2){
        Ryan.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_giraffe);
    }
    else if(a==3){
        Ryan.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_octopus);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Here is my xml code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="500px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="frog"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:name="com.hitchhikingapps.imageviewing.awkwardfragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/awkward"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And here is my  java code

```
public class awkwardfragment extends Fragment{

hello activityCommander;

public interface hello{
    public void changer(int a);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity a=(Activity) context;
    try{
        activityCommander = (hello) a;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(a.toString());
    }
}

Button frog,octopus,giraffe;
int count = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.awkward,container,false);

    frog = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.frog);
    giraffe = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.giraffe);
    octopus = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.octopus);

   frog.setOnClickListener (
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                activityCommander.changer(1);
            }
        }
   );
    giraffe.setOnClickListener (
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    activityCommander.changer(2);
                }
            }
    );

    octopus.setOnClickListener (
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    activityCommander.changer(3);
                }
            }
    );

    return view;
}
```

}

And lastly, my XML code

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="frog"
    android:id="@+id/frog"
    android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="fro" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="giraffe"
    android:id="@+id/giraffe"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frog"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:onClick="gir" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="octopus"
    android:id="@+id/octopus"
    android:layout_below="@+id/giraffe"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="oct" />
```

FloatingActioncode

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Do you have some error ?

Comment: and also do you save FloatingActionButton in your activity_main.xml ?

Comment: Error is unfortunaley, app has stopped. And no, I don't use activity_mail.xml I use content_main.xml. For some reason it doesn't let me add widgets to activity but only to content. It seems to work. here is the xml code to floating action button in my activity_main though

Comment: can you please show your logcat error and also try using view.findViewById() instead of getView()

Comment: thank you, that seemed to fix it crashing, however I still have problems with it not loading up my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change getView to view. getView() == null at this point.

```
    frog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.frog);
    giraffe = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.giraffe);
    octopus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.octopus);
```

Comment: Well now my app doesn't crash XD, however whenever I click a button, Image View doesn't change

Comment: Not sure, but try `Ryan.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_id))`

Comment: .getDrawble is crossed out saying it is deprecated

Comment: Ryan.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_id, this));

Comment: nope, it says ContextCompact can not be applied to (int, imageviewing.MainActivity)

Comment: this ==  MainActivity.this, you need to pass context

Comment: Sorry I have never used ContextCompact before, I replaced it with this code (Ryan.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.awkward_frog,MainActivity.this));) And it still doesn't work :(

Comment: remove this in imageview `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was being dumb XD

Comment: @Duncan no problem. :)